# SFML std::length_error on window.setTitle

Tags: c++, sfml

I started a project with SFML, I want show the fps and the tick on the window title but that is not working:

```
string title =  to_string(frames) + " fps, " + to_string(ticks) + " ticks";
window->setTitle(title);
```

I get this error: **std::length_error**

I have try that and it worked:

```
window->setTitle("5454,grgvfvfvfvfvfvffffffffffrtrrh");
```

**fps and frame** are **int**

So I don't understand, if someone has an answer.

Comment: How long is actually `title`? It can be really long if `frames` or `ticks` are `double`

Comment: **frame** and **tick** are **uint64_t** , but he work with **std::cout** , he show me : _120 fps, 60 ticks_

Comment: I'm not able to replicate the error, could you give extra info about versions, system, platform, etc?

Comment: my bad they are **int** and i work in window 32 bit

Comment: _"I get this error: std::length_error"_ When: upon constructing the string, or upon passing it? Did the compiler not provide any further info than that message?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hello i have find my probleme but i dont understand for what but i just need do :

```
string title =  to_string(frames) + " fps, " + to_string(ticks) + " ticks";
window->setTitle(title.c_str());
```

**".c_str()"** solve my probleme

Answer (score 0):

Here's what the [exception description](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/error/length_error) says:

> Defines a type of object to be thrown as exception. It reports errors that result from attempts to exceed implementation defined length limits for some object.
>
> This exception is thrown by member functions of std::basic_string and std::vector::reserve

Sounds to me like you're using a strange compiler with strange limits.

Comment: I use visual studio 2015